# Using jQuery .innerHeight() as a setter vs just .height()

Tags: jquery

Is there any reason to use jQuery function `.innerHeight()` as a setter instead of `.height()` or does it do exactly the same thing?

Comment: http://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/post/91-jquery-whats-the-difference-between-height-innerheight-and-outerheight/  May be of help - I know, that because I use `box-sizing: border-box` for box-model layout - that I have to use outerHeight instead of height for padding.

Comment: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.innerHeight , https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.height  You can always look at the source to see what the methods actually do.